# My Javascript giving syntax error

Tags: javascript

My Javascript code is giving syntax error, I am unable to find where is the problem:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   function display(id,type){
    alert("Hi");    
   }
</script>
```

onclick event is given below:

```
<map name="Map" id="Map">
  <area shape="rect" coords="24,165,133,182" href="#" onclick="display("#td1","show")" />
  <area shape="rect" coords="23,190,167,209" href="#" />
  <area shape="rect" coords="23,218,165,235" href="#" />
  <area shape="rect" coords="22,242,165,261" href="#" />
  <area shape="rect" coords="23,268,164,286" href="#" />
</map>
```

Comment: `onclick="javascript:display("#td1","show")"`.  Check your quotes.

Comment: ("#td1","show") change those to single quotes.

Comment: convert the onclick event to `onclick="display('#td1','show');"`

Comment: Single quotes. The problem is that by using " several times, the browser thinks you are opening and closing several different quotes. `"diplay("`, `#td1`(which causes the syntax error), `","`, `show`, and `")"`.

Comment: can you show your `td` html as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change quote to single quote

```
<area shape="rect" coords="24,165,133,182" href="#" onclick="javascript:display('#td1','show')" />
```

Comment: Now I am getting below in firebug:

TypeError: document.getElementById(...) is null
 

document.getElementById(id).style.display="inline";

Comment: remove # from id, because # is jquery id selector, you are using nativa javascript ... display('td1','show') />